# Find a point on a line equidistant from the coordinate plane and from the origin point

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't find the ways how to solve this problem:

*On the straight line $$\frac{x+1}{1}=\frac{y-4}{-2}=\frac{z+1}{2}$$ find a point that is equidistant from the coordinate plane $Oxy$ and from the origin point $O(0; 0)$*
Please, can you make me some hints or refer to the helpfull materials? Thank You!

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no such point. The discriminant of the resulting quadratic equation is negative.

Comment: What quadratic equation are you talking about? Which way you were solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want hints, so I'll try to write things in a not obvious way.  The line is a whole set of points, each defined by an X, Y and Z.  You should be able to write two equations, distance from the plane, and distance from the origin point in terms of that X, Y and Z.  So you'll want them to be equal, so you can set those two distances to be the same value.  So you should now have an equation based on X, Y and Z equal to another equation also defined by X, Y and Z.  You'll want to simply that to one variable (e.g. both equations defined by X, Y or Z) so that you can solve that one value.  Good thing you have a line, where X, Y and Z are defined in terms of one another.

Attempt at non-obvious explaination 2, the more explicit version:

Your goal is to find points (Xn, Yn, Zn) such that:

$\ ( Xn + 1 ) = ( Yn - 4) / -2 $

$\ ( Xn + 1 ) = ( Zn + 1) /  2 $

(These two equations being true ensure that this point is on the line.)

And "is equidistant from the coordinate plane Oxy and from the origin point O(0;0)"

The distance to the coordinate plane 0xy is $\ |Zn| $  The distance to the origin point O(0;0) is $\sqrt( (Xn-0)^2 + (Yn-0)^2 ) $  These two must be equal, so $\ |Zn| = sqrt( (Xn-0)^2 + (Yn-0)^2 ) $

You can rewrite the entire equations, either in terms of some new variable $\ t$ or in terms of either $\ Xn, Yn$, or $\ Zn$ 
Either way, you should end up with a quadratic function that identify the two solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it was too much not obvious for me :)
I've tried to find the distance between the line given and the origin point, I've got $\sqrt{5}$
But now I don't even understand, how to find the distance between $Oxy$ and my line? Or should I look for the distance between some point at the line and plane?
And what does it even mean, *...in terms of that X, Y and Z...* etc?

Comment: @Alex does that make more sense?

Comment: yes, I think, I understand now... Huge thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should observe that the given plane passes through the origin, and so you need a point of the line whose projection on $Oxy$ is $O$. Take the perpendicular to $Oxy$ at $0$ and find where they cross.

Comment: Thank you for reply! What did you mean here: _Take the perpendicular to Oxy at 0_ ?
at point $O(0;0;0)$ or what does this zero mean?

Comment: Yes, at point O.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error in the problem, as there are no such points.

The distance of a point to the $x$-$y$ plane is simply the absolute value of its $z$-coordinate. Converting the implicit equations of the line into parametric form produces $(t-1,4-2t,2t-1)$, so after squaring both distances, we’re looking for solutions of $$(t-1)^2+(4-2t)^2+(2t-1)^2=(2t-1)^2.$$ The discriminant of this quadratic equation is $(-18)^2-4\cdot5\cdot17 = -16$, therefore it has no real roots.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. But could you explain your method more detail? How did you get this result? Sorry for my stupidness

Comment: @Alex I’m not sure what more there is to explain. The implicit-to-parametric conversion is well known: set all of the expressions in the implicit equations equal to $t$ and rearrange. The left-hand side of the quadratic equation comes directly from the formula for the distance between two points. The discriminant of a quadratic equation and what it says about the roots is also something that you should’ve learned by now.

Comment: Yes, I understood how did you get parametric form, but why is this equality? The distance between two points is $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$, isn't it? And I am more interested in the right-hand side of your equation. Where did it come from? Why is there are the same term $(2t-1)^2$ both on the left- and right-hand side? Sorry one more time

Comment: Two distances must be equal. How else would you express this but with an equality? As for the rest of your questions, reread my answer. They’re all explicitly covered in it already.